# Getting SSL errors when using cURL, wget and Python on my Ubuntu server

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a pretty fresh version of Lubuntu 19.04 running on my Tinker Board, downloaded from ELAR Systems. I want to get an SSL Certificate using Certbot, which is where I get the Python error:

```
File "/tmp/tmp.7Ta16YELv4/pipstrap.py", line 177, in <module>
  sys.exit(main())
File "/tmp/tmp.7Ta16YELv4/pipstrap.py", line 158, in main
  for path, digest in PACKAGES]
File "/tmp/tmp.7Ta16YELv4/pipstrap.py", line 117, in hashed_download
  response = opener(using_https=parsed_url.scheme == 'https').open(url)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
  response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
  '_open', req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1241, in https_open
  context=self._context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
  raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)>
```

I expect that this error is related to the SSL error I get when using wget and cURL.

## wget:

```
tinker@ELAR-Systems:~$ wget stackoverflow.com
--2019-12-29 22:33:53--  http://stackoverflow.com/
Resolving stackoverflow.com (stackoverflow.com)... 151.101.1.69, 151.101.65.69, 151.101.129.69, ...
Connecting to stackoverflow.com (stackoverflow.com)|151.101.1.69|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://stackoverflow.com/ [following]
--2019-12-29 22:33:54--  https://stackoverflow.com/
Connecting to stackoverflow.com (stackoverflow.com)|151.101.1.69|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify stackoverflow.com's certificate, issued by ‘CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to stackoverflow.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

## cURL

```
tinker@ELAR-Systems:~$ curl -X GET -I https://pypi.python.org
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

I checked the folder `/usr/share/ca-certificates` which is empty, and when I enter `sudo update-ca-certificates`, it says `0 added, 0 removed; done.`. Is this of any relevance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this: `sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/cacert.org && sudo wget -P /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/cacert.org http://www.cacert.org/certs/root.crt http://www.cacert.org/certs/class3.crt && sudo update-ca-certificates`

Comment: @IainShelvington wow thanks, it fixed all of my problems :)

Answer (score 2):

Use below snippet to ignore ssl checks

import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context